# PDO executing query inserts more rows in my database then it should

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, execute

I made a little script and now when I call the script the PDO should insert the row 1 time and not twice with an value that is not set.

This is the first code

```
function checkContent($content, $lang){
  preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $content, $matches);

  $items = array();
  foreach($matches[1] as $match){
    $items[] = explode("|", $match);
  }
  foreach($items as $item):
    $module = $item[0];
    $slug = $item[1];
    switch($module){
        case "translation";
          $content = str_replace("[{$module}|{$slug}]", translation($slug, $lang), $content);
        break;
    }
  endforeach;
  return $content;
}
```

In this code above it calls the function translation();

```
function translation($trans, $langTag){
    global $cms_db;

    $sql = $cms_db->prepare("SELECT translation FROM translations WHERE uniqueName = ? AND language = ?");
    $sql->execute(array($trans,$langTag));
    $translation = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(empty($translation)):
        $sql = $cms_db->prepare("INSERT INTO translations (uniqueName, translation, language, new) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $sql->execute(array($trans,$trans,$langTag,'1'));
        //EDIT, even with a die here, it enters 2 rows.
        //die()
        return $trans;
    else:
        return $translation['translation'];
    endif;
}
```

In this code, is should enter 1 row in the database with the values.

```
$trans = "button.next";
$langTag = "NL";
```

Even if I use a die() in the function or not, it will insert two rows, one with the values good and the second one the $langTag is randomly changed to: favicon.ico.

The weirdest thing is that I am not using favicon.ico anywhere in my code.

I hope you guys can help me, maybe its me not looking good, but I get a little frustrated about it

Thanks in advance!

EDIT, NOT FIXED
The problem was that I forgot the meta favicon tag. Now it works fine, does someone can explain to me why the favicon is send to my script in the ?lang=XXX parameter?

**EDIT 2**
Too bad, I thought it was fixed, but today I got the values again in my database. This is really frustrated that it puts a random thing in my database

**After a while of angry coding :P**

I think I finally fixed it, I think it was the problem that I included some js/css that was not necessary and that was loading my script also.

Comment: You site also requests for a favicon. You webserver (apache or whatever) redirects this request to your script, that's why script runs twice. Check for `.htaccess` file in a dir or virtual host config.

Answer (score -1):

Try to trace count of script calls per request writing to a log file (dont forget flock() it).

Obviously youre script is called twice for some reason, you should analyze access logs of http server too.